# How to convert "animated" text in a document to static text?

Tags: command-line, text

When I analyze the output from Racon, which I got on GitHub, it has dynamic "animated" text as the output from the STDERR.

For example, when I cat the file, it looks like this:

> [racon::Polisher::initialize] aligned overlap 624/2265116

The text then "animates" and overwrites itself to say the next number:

> [racon::Polisher::initialize] aligned overlap 1954/2265116

The end result is that there are 220 megabytes worth of data stored in 7 lines.

I would like to get each of these steps listed individually, but when I analyze the text with any text editor, it crashes.

The only tools I have available to me are command line tools.

Comment: Chances are the vast majority of the text file are terminal control sequences to move the cursor and rewrite the new text.  It's hard to say what's going wrong with your text editors without more detailed information, but if the file is simply too large, you can use `split` to break the file into smaller pieces and look at it part by part.

Comment: Depending on what the actual output is - maybe there's a carriage return followed by a completely new line for each update, or just a few backspaces and updated numbers  -  it may be sufficient to filter it through `col -b`.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I think it might be worth leaving up, however, since it's incredibly difficult to describe what's going on to look for answers. I imagine there are other people in the future who would describe this as "animated text"

Comment: @CayetanoGonçalves that's one of the points of closing questions as duplicates - to help people searching using different terms for the same thing.

Comment: @muru Ah I thought it would be deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be sufficient to just remove carriage return ( `<CR>` / `^M` / `0x0D` / `\r`) chars (unless we get more info on the input). Pipe it through

```
tr -d $'\r'
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just browse through it with `less`?

`less` does not do any of this fancy terminal escape sequence stuff. It will just display escape sequences in inverted text. This will have the side effect of random workds like `ESC` appearing in inverted type, but if you only need to read through it, this shouldn't matter.

Invoke it like this: `less <filename>`